# Running a shell from within a docker container succeeds but not as an entrypoint ("no such file or directory" error)

Tags: docker, shell, containers

I made a small container that runs a single shell script.
Its Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM centos:centos7.9.2009

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/test
COPY ./ /var/lib/test/
RUN yum -y localinstall /var/lib/test/*.rpm

ENTRYPOINT ["sh /var/lib/test/test.sh"]
```

However, when I run the image, it returns the error:

```
#docker run -it test:1.0
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:290: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh /var/lib/test/test.sh\": stat sh /var/lib/test/test.sh: no such file or directory".
```

The script file definitely exists as I can replace its entrypoint with bash and manually execute it:

```
# docker run -it --entrypoint bash test:1.0
[root@e9361c3e67fa /]# sh /var/lib/test/test.sh
Shell script starts...
```

I read similar posts and confirmed that the permission of the script is correct, the return codes inside it were all `LF`.

And the shell script is really simple:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test"
exit 0
```

What else can cause this problem?

Comment: What is the content of `test.sh`

Comment: I have edited my post. It fails no matter what the content of the shell is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the entrypoint to:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/var/lib/test/test.sh"]
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Docker can insert a `sh -c` wrapper for you if you remove the JSON-array syntax, so `ENTRYPOINT /var/lib/test/test.sh` would be shorter and equivalent.  Note that this form essentially prevents the script from receiving any additional arguments passed as the container command.

Answer (score 1):

When you interactively run `sh test.sh`, the shell breaks it into two words for you.  The JSON-array form of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` (and also `RUN`) requires you to explicitly break up the words yourself, though.  As you have it written in a single array entry is the same as writing a single word in quotes `'sh test.sh'` at a shell prompt.

The most expedient answer is to break this into two words

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/var/lib/test/test.sh"]
```

However: you shouldn't need the explicit `sh` at all.  If the script is executable (as in `chmod +x`) and begins with the line `#!/bin/sh`, then the system will be able to figure out that it's a standard Bourne shell script.  You should be able to just run

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/lib/test/test.sh"]
# (or CMD ["/var/lib/test/test.sh"])
```

without directly saying `sh` anywhere.